# How to remove row having different value in rows

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe and I want to remove two rows having not relevant value in my dataframe

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|                 url|             address|                name|        online_order|          book_table|         rate|               votes|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|https://www.zomat...|27th Main, 2nd Se...|Rock View Family ...|                 Yes|                  No|        3.3/5|                   8|
|https://www.zomat...|1152, 22nd Cross,...|           OMY Grill|                 Yes|                  No|        3.8/5|                  34|
|xperience this pl...|        ('Rated 3.0'| 'RATED\n  Yummy ...| I got choco chip...|strangely they di...| ('Rated 3.0'|" """"RATED\n  Th...|
|ing new to Bangalore|Chip����\x83����\...| ����\x83����\x83...| I was really hap...| Service was quic...| ('Rated 4.0'| 'RATED\n  Visite...|
|https://www.zomat...|1086/A, Twin Tuli...|          Wings Mama|                 Yes|                  No|         null|                   0|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

and my dataframe is look like this after removing the rows

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+----------+-----+-----+
|                 url|             address|                name|online_order|book_table| rate|votes|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+----------+-----+-----+
|https://www.zomat...|27th Main, 2nd Se...|Rock View Family ...|         Yes|        No|3.3/5|    8|
|https://www.zomat...|1152, 22nd Cross,...|           OMY Grill|         Yes|        No|3.8/5|   34|
|https://www.zomat...|1086/A, Twin Tuli...|          Wings Mama|         Yes|        No| null|    0|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+----------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to filter out the row using regular expression

```
expr = "^http.*"
df=df.filter(df["url"].rlike(expr))
```

Comment: or a simple like : `df["url"].like('http%')`. But the problem comes problem from the way you ingest your file.